# Write number of rows to file name

Tags: python

I dont have any idea how to update my code below to the level that I can write the amount of changed row - in the CSV - to the file name.

I have did some stuff with count and row, but it is making any sense.

Can somebody give me some tips

```
import csv
import glob
import os

rows = []

for in_csv in glob.glob('C:/code/convert/Image/In/*.csv'):
    print in_csv

    with open(in_csv, 'rb') as f_input:
        reader = csv.reader(f_input)

        try:
            all = []
            row = next(reader)
            row.insert(0, 'l_panoramic')
            all.append(row)

            for k, row in enumerate(reader):
                all.append(['l_panoramic_{:06}'.format(k)] + row)

            name, ext = os.path.splitext(in_csv)

            with open("{}_{}{}".format(name, len(rows), ext), 'wb') as f_output:
                writer = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter = ';')
                writer.writerows(all)
                print  "  {} lines found".format(len(rows))
        except StopIteration as e:
            print "  No lines found"
```

Comment: _to the level that I can write the amount of changed row - in the CSV - to the file name_

What is the amount of the changed row?

Comment: Do you want to write in the second file, the number of rows of the first?

Comment: I want to write to the new file, in Out. But to the file name. So it takes the file name - 170728.csv (in the 'In' Folder) and in the 'Out' folder 170728_1915.csv (for having 1915 rows in the CSV. That means in my case 1915 panoramics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done using the `glob` library to create your list of CSV files. Use [`splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.splitext) to take then existing filename and split it into a filename and extension, the number of rows can then be easily added using a `format()` statement as follows:

```
import csv
import glob
import os

rows = []

for in_csv in glob.glob('a*.csv'):
    print in_csv

    with open(in_csv, 'rb') as f_input:
        reader = csv.reader(f_input)

        try:
            row = next(reader)
            row.insert(0, 'L_panoramic')
            rows.append(row)

            for k, row in enumerate(reader):
                rows.append(['l_panoramic_{:06}'.format(k)] + row)

            name, ext = os.path.splitext(in_csv)

            with open("{}_{}{}".format(name, len(rows), ext), 'wb') as f_output:        
                writer = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter = ';')
                writer.writerows(rows)
                print  "  {} lines found".format(len(rows))
        except StopIteration as e:
            print "  No lines found"
```

You were already creating a list of rows to be written, so once this list is complete, you will know how many rows there are. With this you can then open the output file with the number of rows added to the name, and write all the rows to it.

Comment: Hi, ok I think I am getting where you are going. But where do i leave my In and Output folder?

Comment: I just simplified your logic for the sake of simplicity. It should just write the files back into the same folder at the moment. You could also use `os.path.join()` to prepend a different output folder (which is better than using string concatenation as it correctly handles file separators)

Comment: Ok, i get that. There is a error coming up: TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: 2.7 if I remove newline to:  with open(str(in_csv), 'rb',) as f_input: -  then It blocks on all.apend(row) - with StopIteration

Comment: `newline` is a Python 3.x keyword, I have updated it to Python 2.x. If `glob.glob()` is used, it returns filenames as strings, so there is no need to convert it to a string with `str()`. `all()` is a Python function, which is why I renamed it `rows`.

Comment: keeps stopping on line row = next(reader):     row = next(reader)
StopIteration

Comment: You probably have read in a text file that has no lines. I suggest you add a `print in_csv`, and take a look at the file it stops on.

Comment: correct, with al the testing it generated a empty file. Iwrite now the file with a number, but it is always filename_0.csv.I updated the current code. I still need the all = [] on line 19\

Comment: The code is updated, this is the only way I can get it working without errors, like exporting it multiple times in the same file (double or triple). But the count on the rows keeps giving zero like filename_0.csv